# Extract Latin numbers from Arabic text

Tags: python, regex, arabic, python-3.9

I have a substring of Arabic text with Latin numerals in it such as:

```
text = قيمة بيع الدولار 550
```

I need to extract the number from the text, but I'm struggling with the regex that would work for this. I think the fact that the numbers are going left to right and letters going right to left are causing me issues...I'm admittedly not well versed in regex so I'm hoping there's just a trick to it I'm missing it.
Here are a couple things I've tried:

```
re.findall(r'قيمة بيع الدولار \d+', text)
re.findall(r'\d+ قيمة بيع الدولار', text)
```

Both of these return empty lists.

If I search for simply `re.findall(r'\d+', text)` it does successfully return a list of all the numbers in the text, so I'm pretty sure it's issue to do with searching for BOTH Arabic and Latin in the same string.

The full text of what I'm searching looks something like this below, so if I search ONLY for the numbers, it returns stuff I don't need/want. I also need to be able to differentiate between the numbers that are identified as "الدولار" versus "اليورو". There are NO newline characters in the text.

```
Text =    "ها هي قيم العملة يوم 4/2/2022 الساعة 9:00:
    
    قيمة بيع الدولار 550
    قيمة بيع اليورو 600
    قيمة شراء الدولار 700
    قيمة شراء اليورو 701"

x = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
```

returns

```
x = ['4', '2', '2022', '9', '00', '550', '600', '700', '701']
```

Edit: In this case, I do NOT want to have a list with 4, 2, 2022, 9, 00. I can usually count on the numbers I do want to be in the same order, but not always. I also need to be certain which number is associated with which set of text because the text contains information about what currency the number is for (roughly translated the first line is "the value to sell the dollar is 550")

Comment: `re.findall(r"\d+", Text)`

Comment: As noted in the question, this does not return what I am looking for. 

"The full text of what I'm searching looks something like this below, so if I search ONLY for the numbers, it returns stuff I don't need/want." 

You've just given me regex to search for just numbers...

Comment: Note that "latin numbers" are arabic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely understand what you're saying with mixing right-to-left and left-to-right.

The below seems to work (highlighting bugged, but matches on the right are as expected). Since you want to differentiate them anyway, how about 2 separate regexes?

```
الدولار.(\d+)
```

```
اليورو.(\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hXYNk2/1

Comment: Holy moly! Never seen that site and I will be using the heck out of it! Thanks for the tip! And I agree - I think that set of two regex matches will work best; I was missing the . match in my version and now I'm getting the number strings as desired with the full (.\d+) accompanying the Arabic text. Cheers!

Comment: Slight typo, if you haven't already corrected it, you probably want to leave the . out of the capture group. Edited my post. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = Text.split()
numl = [num for num in s if num.isnumeric()]
```

This makes a list of "words" separated out by each space, then a list of the numbers. So don't have to use regex.

Comment: What happens when there's no space between the number and the preceding or following word? :-)

Comment: Don't think that is the case in this question with the format shown. It seems that stand alone numbers are wanted.

Comment: The OP has given an example of `"9:00"` which is split into `9` and `00`, so I'd certainly say it is the case with the format shown.

Comment: Yeah those are present in the text but are not what is required in the output.

Comment: I must have missed it, I don't see anywhere where OP has said they do not what that in the output.

Comment: Just looked again and the final sentence is not there so maybe it was edited out ??? There was also a bit about thinking it was something to do with looking at Arabic and Latin together which is not there either ?!!

Comment: "it returns stuff I don't need/want."

Comment: @InhirCode is correct - I DON'T want the time or date in my set of numbers. 

Should have included this clarification, but I've added it to the post now - the Arabic text includes some information about the number (the currency). So I need to be sure that the number is associated with that specific text so I can turn several bits of the information into a line in a dataframe. That's why just getting a list of numbers out is not my preferred solution, although this answer does work in that it extracts the numeric information.

Comment: @Alicia - thanks for clarifying - Peace to you